# Is there a way to control and monitor each instances of parallel running selenium test in testng

Tags: spring-mvc, selenium, testng, selenium-grid

I'm trying to set up a web page from which user could set the parameters for a selenium test and when submitted would run the selenium test using TestNG on web server machine. I'm looking for a way to get access or handle to each parallel running test instance, So the client(from the browser) could control each of them separately and also have their log displayed real-time on the web page. Can this be done?

Comment: what do you mean by monitoring? what are the things you are looking for ? And this feature (whatever you are looking for)  should be in selenium not testng. The console of the selenium grid gives you some insight.

Comment: We would have a page where you will be able to select various parameters like which tests to be run, on which browser and so on. And when you submit it. It should run the selenium test in the server machine and result (logs,screenshots,status) should be displayed back in client browser in realtime. And if we have parallel test running, client should able to stop any of them separately.   Something like what browserstack and sauce lab provides.

Comment: 1. logs,screenshots and status - are things which are in your control which you will collect in your testcase and you can display them as you want.
2. client should able to stop any of them separately - This you should be able to do using session id. Each testcase will be associated with a sessionid/remotewebdriver, using the driver/session id you should be able to terminate the testcase.

Further to know the state of a particular session you can scrape the grid console and find out more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can show log entries on the page while the test is running [using jGrowl](http://jonausten.info/2014/06/23/how-to-add-a-jgrowl-wrapper-to-your-selenium-framework/).

As far as thread handling is concerned, as long as you generate instances of your webdriver in the DataProvider and then pass that instance into the test methods from the data provider, then each one will be separately controlled and you can run multiple browsers simultaneously.

Most importantly, if your using Spring, then the DataProvider method wont work because of the order of things loading before tests.  So, in that case you need to handle threads with a custom ThreadManager singleton pattern class.   When using Spring, its much more complex and too hard for me to explain here, but its doable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. yeah i m using spring mvc and testng is  running the selenium tests in parallel. Im thinking of using  async method in spring. Can you think of some urls that could help me.

Comment: I don't use Async and i dont know how to use Async, probably because I am using TestNG to fork my threads.  I do use a singleton WebDriverManager class using ThreadLocal.  So, not sure if that helps you.  The only Spring annotations I use are basically Component, Configuration, Autowired, Bean, and RunWith.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you run parallel tests using testng. Since testng is handling the parallel execution.It seems we don't  have handle to those each parallel running instances. Maybe we can get some control using session id while implementing selenium grid but for standalone web driver i do not see any control over the instances.